# Celery - One task calls a smaller task n times with different parameters

Tags: python, flask, celery

The basic idea here is I want one celery task to call a method n times, which will then group a number of smaller tasks, with a different value for the task's parameter each time.

The first task will be a for loop that calls a method each time, which in turn will [group](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#groups) a number of smaller tasks. The first task will update a web page with the progress of the for loop.

What would be the best way of doing this?

I've tried a couple of ways, including just simply delaying the tasks, however I find that one of the workers gets locked in the first task, and then any of the smaller tasks that get assigned to it don't get processed.

I can't see it working with [chains](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chains).

I currently have it working using the [-Ofair](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/whatsnew-3.1.html?highlight=inqueue#caveats) flag to disable prefetching however this makes it very slow when getting the results.

celeryTasks.py

```
@app.task()
def sweepSubnets(subnets):
    ...
    for subnet in subnets:
        print "subnet:{0}".format(subnet)
        sweep.runSweep(subnet, finished)
        finished += 1
        percent = (float((float(finished)/ float(noSubnets))) * 100)
        current_task.update_state(state='PROGRESS',
        meta={'process_percent': percent, 'subnet' : subnet})

    results = sweep.getResults()
    return results

@app.task()
def ping(ip):
    result = os.system("ping -W 1 -c 1 " + ip + " >/dev/null")
    return (ip,result)
```

sweep.py

```
def runSweep(self, subnet, number):
    if self.checkSubnet(subnet):
         print "Pinging {0}".format(subnet)
         netAdd, nodeAdd, poolSize = self.splitSubnet(subnet) 
         pingResults = self.queuePings(netAdd, nodeAdd, poolSize)
         activeResults = self.getActiveResults(pingResults)

        # Adds a tuple to the results list (subnet, active hosts, total hosts)
        self.results.append({"subnet":subnet, "activeNo":len(activeResults), "totalNo":len(pingResults), "active":activeResults, "total":pingResults, "number":number})
    else:
        self.results.append({"subnet":subnet, "activeNo":0, "totalNo":0, "active":[], "total":[], "number":number})

def queuePings(self, netAdd, nodeAdd, poolSize):
    from celeryTasks import ping

    ipToPing = []

    # For each address, puts the address on the job queue
    for i in range(1, poolSize):
        # Checks if the node address is over 254 and increases the network address if so
        nodeAdd = int(nodeAdd) + 1
        if int(nodeAdd) > 255:
            nodeAdd = 0
            netAdd = netAdd.split(".")
            netAdd = netAdd[0] + "." + netAdd[1] + "." + str(int(netAdd[2]) + 1)

        ipToPing.append("{0}.{1}".format(netAdd, nodeAdd))

    job = group(ping.s(ip) for ip in ipToPing)

    result = job.apply_async()
    print "Getting Results"
    return result.get()
```

Comment: It might help to see your code to know exactly what you are going for.

Comment: So one problem I see you have and this is probably a side not is you have a task waiting on results from tasks which themselves are waiting for results from tasks. If I'm understanding your code correctly.  This is a bad idea as can very easily cause locking conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that may come across a similar problem here's what I did:

I used a group to run all the pings, as before, but I saved the group's id so that I could return it and restore the results later, rather than getting them in the larger task.

```
job = group(ping.s(ip) for ip in ipToPing)
result = job.apply_async()
while not result.ready():
    time.sleep(0.1)
result.save()
return result.id
```

I then had a list of group id's that I restored and worked on once the bigger task was finished.

```
for job in jobList:
     jobIDs = GroupResult.restore(job)
     results = jobIDs.get()
```